# Aggregate by year and month for a POSIX variable

Tags: r

I have a dataset of the following form.

```
        country            datetime       x
1 United States 2008-01-01 00:00:00 5962.06
2 United States 2008-01-02 00:00:00 6002.74
3 United States 2008-01-03 00:00:00 6040.98
4 United States 2008-01-04 00:00:00 6031.44
5 United States 2008-01-05 00:00:00 6029.91
6 United States 2008-01-06 00:00:00 6025.24
```

For me time (hours, minutes, seconds) and days of the week are irrelevant, but I want to aggregate the values of variable "x" by `country`, year and month. Is there any straightforward way of doing this?

Comment: It's going to depend on the class of the "country" and "datatime" columns. We can guess that "country" is a factor variable and that "datatime" is POSIXct, but it would be better if you posted str() on the object. In the absence of direction from you, we will also need to guess at what sort of aggregation you wnat. Sum? Mean? Max?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is possibly to use `strftime` to format your `datetime` as a character vector that contains only the year and month.

Assuming your column `datetime` is of class `POSIXct`, and that your `data.frame` is called `dat`:

```
dat$shortdate <- strftime(dat$datetime, format="%Y/%m")
dat
        country   datetime       x shortdate
1 United States 2008-01-01 5962.06   2008/01
2 United States 2008-01-02 6002.74   2008/01
3 United States 2008-01-03 6040.98   2008/01
4 United States 2008-01-04 6031.44   2008/01
5 United States 2008-01-05 6029.91   2008/01
6 United States 2008-01-06 6025.24   2008/01
```

Then its a simple matter to use your favourite aggregation method to summarise the data.  For example, using `plyr`:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(dat, .(shortdate), summarize, mean_x=mean(x))

  shortdate   mean_x
1   2008/01 6015.395
```

Comment: Perfect. Perfect! Thanks, Andrie. Just out of curiosity, is there any way of parsing by year, month and also week?

Comment: You can easily specify week number (i.e. first week of January is 1, last week of December is ~52) with "%U" or "%W".  The options are described at the bottom of the help page for `?strptime`

Comment: Or use lubridate's year and month functions.

Answer (score 1):

Given Andrie's better solution this will mainly be an exercise in POSIXlt illustration. Using the assumptions about the classes of your variables noted above and using `mean` as the aggregating function:

```
aggregate(dfrm$x, list(dfrm$country, as.POSIXlt(dfrm$datetime)$year, 
                       as.POSIXlt(dfrm$datetime)$mon), FUN=mean)
         Group.1 Group.2 Group.3        x
1  United States     108       0 6015.395
```

Note that one could add 1900 to the POSIXlt year value to recover a year and use the month value as an index into the R constant vector 'month.abb', and adding nice column labels:

```
aggregate(dfrm$x, list(Country=dfrm$country, 
                       Year=1900+as.POSIXlt(dfrm$datetime)$year, 
                       Month=month.abb[1+as.POSIXlt(dfrm$datetime)$mon]), 
FUN=mean)
         Country Year Month        x
1  United States 2008   Jan 6015.395
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zoo::as.yearmon`:

```
 aggregate(x ~ country * as.yearmon(datetime), FUN=mean, data=dat)

 as.yearmon(datetime)       country        x
1             ene 2008 United States 6015.395
```